# Can't upgrade and build iOS on react native 0.65

Tags: ios, ruby, react-native, build, cocoapods

Trying to upgrade to 0.65 react version with the help of react native upgrade helper.

What I tried:

```
1) rm -rf nodu_modules && cd/ios && rm -rf Podfile.lock Pods && pod deintegrate && pod update && pod install
```

Here is what I have in my Podfile.

```
require_relative '../node_modules/react-native/scripts/react_native_pods'
require_relative '../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/native_modules'

platform :ios, '13.2'

target 'Test' do
  config = use_native_modules!

  use_react_native!(
    :path => config[:reactNativePath],
    # to enable hermes on iOS, change `false` to `true` and then install pods
    :hermes_enabled => false
  )

  use_flipper!()

  post_install do |installer|
    react_native_post_install(installer)
  end


  pod 'React-Core', :path => '../node_modules/react-native'

end
```

What kind of a problem I have?

While pod update/pod install/pod install --repo-update, I have:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

typo when deleting node_modules? You put nodu_modules. And then re-install node_modules with yarn/npm?

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.